# OnActivityResult() returning null data

Tags: java, android, android-activity, onactivityresult

I know this question has been asked many times and i followed all the steps correctly but still getting null data in my FirstApplication

FirstApplication starting an intent to get result from a library class using Mainactivity that is initialised using the activity variable in a constructor:

```
 sendIntent.putExtra("data", bundle);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        activity.startActivityForResult(sendIntent, requestCode);
    }
```

SecondApplication getting the intent and doing necessary operation

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();

    Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("data");

    if (bundle!=null){


        type = bundle.getString("type");

        num1 = Integer.parseInt(bundle.getString("num1"));
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(bundle.getString("num2"));


        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("add")){

            result = String.valueOf(num1+num2);


        }else {

            result = String.valueOf(num1-num2);

        }

    }
```

Sending result to FirstApplication

```
    Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();

    if (bundle1!=null){

        Intent send = new Intent();

        bundle1.putString("result", result);
        send.putExtra("datasend", bundle1);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, send);
        finish();

    }
```

Receiving result in FirstApplication MAinActivity

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle bundle = data.getBundleExtra("datasend");
            result = bundle.getString("result");

        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

But here i am receiving resultCode 0 and data null. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```java
sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

By calling `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` you are setting the second activity on the top of the back stack and cancelling the effect of `startActivityForResult()`

So it should be removed to get back the result